# Repeat Part of Image in a Single Face

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

Is there a way to make texture repeatable, like example below?

I have one general texture:
[image]

And I want to repeat symbol B like this, but without cutting the face, using same texture:
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To repeat an image texture in single face you have to math a bit UV vectors.
I used same UVmap from ABC material for second material BBB with this node tree ...

- Crop and repeat UV by 0,333 with Modulo (Math) node on X axis
- Offset UV by 1/3 on X axis to get letter B in the view segment

[image]